# .csv did not save all tabs

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv

I downloaded a database in .csv and made pivot tables in different tabs.

I saved the file without complications, but when I went to open it, only the tab with the database appeared, the other tabs did not appear.

Does anyone know if I can recover the data from the other tabs?

Comment: CSV files don’t store tabs. It just stores data of the tab that was opened when you exported the CSV.

Comment: it's called "sheets" and csv is just a very simple text files so how can it store multiple sheets? You should save the file as a better format like xlsx, xlsb, ods...

Comment: CSV is the TEXT file format..

Comment: That will happen if you you save the file as `CSV`. There should have been a warning about losing the other worksheets.  Try saving the file as `xlsx` or `xlsm` type.

Comment: Excrl WILL warn you, unless you tell Excel to not tell you again, when you save a file in a format that does not support the features. If you disable warnings you need to know what that format supports.

Answer (score 3):

`.csv` or *C*omma *S*eparated *V*alues is a spreadsheet format that can contain only values like numbers or text separated by a comma or other such separators, in a simple text file. It can not contain other things like various sheets or charts and other such objects.

> Does anyone know if I can recover the data from the other tabs?

If you have saved a file as .csv, and closed Excel, then all such data is already lost from the file. If you're lucky, however, excel might have autosaved some of the file.

Answer (score 2):

Always read the pop-up warnings:

[image]

Comment: With Excel 365 you can finally disable these notices, which is nice if you are aware of the format's features. But, if you're unaware and you've told Excel to stop warning you, situations like OPs may happen.

Answer (score 0):

You're out of luck. You need to either allow Excel to warn you of these feature/format compatibility issues, or you need to be aware of them yourself.

Excel will warn you if you're saving a file in a format that does not support the features the file contains, but in the most recent versions of Excel they allow you to dismiss these warnings and hide them, which is nice if you know the features your format supports, but if you aren't aware of the features you should not hide these warnings.

You can re-enable the warnings, if they have been disabled, in Excel Settings. I strongly suggest you do this.

Answer (score -1):

As comments have stated, .csv is a simple text file format. It can't store multiple sheets, pivottables, or any other advanced feature. It can't even store font changes.

If you open a .csv file using a text editor such as Notepad, you'll see the data shown exactly like this:

Column1,Column2,Column3,Column4
1,2,3,4
5,6,7,8

When Excel opens a .csv file, it automatically parses it into rows and columns, using the commas to mark the columns; however, this doesn't change the underlying structure of the file, it's just Excel displaying it to you in a format you can work with.

.csv is widely used for distributing data because it's extremely simple, so almost any application can open the file and make use of it. You don't need a copy of Excel or OpenOffice or anything else to make use of the data.

If you want to save more advanced features, like PivotTables, formulas, or formatting, you'll need to use File | Save As to save a copy of the file in one of the Excel formats, .xlsx, .xlsm, .xlsb, etc.